# apply css style to a div within an angular js directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

In my directive I am handling jqueryui.resizeable  I was having an issue where it was very jittery and froze ALOT in firefox. So i took someones suggestion and when the directive was triggered I added a div to the DOM ... resized that ... and at the end I snapped the original div to the one i added then get rid of the added div.

This actually completely took care of my jitter issue. The only problem is that during the resize event it should be adding a class to the added div which will make it visible on the screen while resizing .... but that class is not added.

My directive is as follows:

```
directive('resizable', function() {
    return {

    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        callback: '&onResize'
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.resizable({
          helper: function() {
            return (jQuery("<div>").css({
              height: jQuery(this).height(),
              width: jQuery(this).width()
          }).addClass('resizeHelper'));    
        }

        });

        elem.on('resizestop', function (evt, ui) {
            if (scope.callback) { scope.callback(); }
        });
            window.e = elem;
        }
    };
});
```

The css class i wish to add is:

```
.resizeHelper {
    border: 2px dashed #cccccc;    
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

I have setup a plunker to better illustrate the issue im having: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ws64rm?p=preview

If you view source and resize the initial div you will see a class get added that deals with the actual resize event then the original div is snapped to it at the end .... but the css class is never added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `helper` option in jQuery UI for a resizable object is different than the helper option for other APIs in jQuery UI (e.g. draggable). This option expects a simple string to be applied as a class name to the proxy object.

See: http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-helper

The modified code would be,

```
elem.resizable({ helper:'resizeHelper' });
```

Also as a side note, when using angular, it is better to use angular.element as a pseudo for jQuery as it gets loaded into Angular. This is better for testing purposes.

Comment: Ah, I see I was solving a real, but irrelevant, issue with my answer. You nailed it. +1 for solving the root of the issue.

Comment: Perfect ... but +1 to you as well jshanley because i see where you were going as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear to me whether you are trying to select an existing div or create it, but either way, the syntax is incorrect.

To select an existing div you would do:

```
// notice, no angle brackets around 'div'
jQuery('div').css({
  height: elem.height(),
  width: elem.width()
}).addClass('resizeHelper'));
```

To append a new div, you would do:

```
// append opening and closing tag, adding class
elem.append('<div class="resizeHelper"></div>');
// then select the element you just made and apply the css
elem.find('.resizeHelper').css({
  height: elem.height(),
  width: elem.width()
});
```

There is no need to wrap the element as `jQuery(this)` because `elem` is automatically jQuery-wrapped for you by angular if you have included jQuery, or with jQLite otherwise.